# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Single' to type 'System.Int32'

Tags: c#

I am confused by getting the following error:

> ```
> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Single' to type 'System.Int32'.
> ```

I am fetching data and iterating them as follows:

```
public MyFault
{

   public int fault_throw { get; set; }

}

 protected List<MyFault> myfaults = new List<MyFault>();
 foreach (var package in packages2)
    {
       // the following line throws an error
      myfaults.Add(new MyFault {fault_throw=(int)(package["fault_throw"])});
    }
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/303w38b8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

System.Single is a single-precision floating-point number. And I think it is boxed as object in package["fault_throw"]. And you can not unbox a float to an int. You can use the `Convert.ToInt32()` Method, if you want to convert a boxed float to an integer.

Comment: Thanks Issa, what should I use whenI change  from `int` to `float`  as follows  `public float fault_throw { get; set; }`

Comment: It is giving error. Therefore, I have tried to use `Convert.ToSingle()` and it works.

Comment: which type ist package["fault_throw"] ?

Comment: _"you cant cast a floating-point number to an Integer"_ -- sure you can. What you can't do is unbox a `float` as an `int`. The OP unfortunately did not provide a good enough code example, but based on the reported error, I assume that `package["fault_throw"]` returns the type `object`. If it returned the type `float`, the cast would work.

Comment: float s = 2.8F;
            object f = s;
            int a = Convert.ToInt32(f); ... it works

Comment: _"float s = 2.8F; object f = s; int a = Convert.ToInt32(f); ... it works"_ -- I never said it didn't. I'm taking issue with your use of the word "must". I see though that you have edited your answer to address that error as well. Thank you for correcting that problem.

Answer (score 4):

Without [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, it's impossible to know for sure what the problem in your code is.

However, based on the error message it seems likely that the expression `package["fault_throw"]` returns type `object`, and contains a boxed instance of a `float` value.

Under that assumption, all you really need is to unbox the value correctly, and *then* cast it. E.g. `(int)(float)package["fault_throw"]`.

Now, that said: if you don't know in advance what the actual type of the value returned by the expression `package["fault_throw"]` is, then the `Convert.ToInt32()` method would be appropriate. It can handle a variety of inputs (including `string`) and it will do whatever it can to convert the value to an `int`.

But if you know for sure the value is a `float` (i.e. `System.Single`), then it would be more efficient to just unbox the value correctly and cast it (as my example above).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `CInt() or Integer.Parse`
Maybe `Convert.ToInt32()` can work too.

Comment: You mean as follows `fault_throw=(Integer.Parse)(package["fault_throw"])`

Comment: `Int32.Parse(package["fault_throw"])` or `int.Parse(..)`

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32(package["fault_throw"].toString())` even this doesn't work?

Comment: I have got the following error with applying `Input string was not in a correct format.`

Comment: Can you provide me the contents of `package[fault_throw]`?

Comment: Try `Convert.ToInt32(package["fault_throw"].toString().Trim())` @ilyasUyanik Maybe the input is too long for int32 try int64.

Comment: Converting to a string just to convert back to an int is pure folly.  It's the absolute most inefficient way to solve this problem.